# Entity Framework: Add new object and link to 2nd new object via navigational property

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I have a scenario where I'm creating two new objects which are linked via a navigational property (foreign key), eg:

```
            ClientAccount client = new ClientAccount {
                ......
                AccountTypeId = 1
            };

            ClientEmailAddress email = new ClientEmailAddress {
                ClientId = client.Id,
                EmailAddress = "test@test.com"
            };

           client.FkClientEmailAddresses.Add(email);
```

When I try to save though, via `dbContext.SaveChanges();`, I get an exception:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`client_email_addresses`, CONSTRAINT `FK_client_email_addresses_client_accounts` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `client_accounts` (`client_account_id`))
```

I believe this is because the ClientAccount object does not have an ID at the time I'm assigning it to the ClientEmailAdresss object.

Can anyone confirm whether what I'm trying to do is possible? I'd rather not have multiple .SaveChanges calls.

Comment: is the `ClientAccount` id auto generated?

Comment: Yes it is. It's a MySQL AUTO INCREMENT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this instead:

```
        ClientAccount client = new ClientAccount {
            ......
            AccountTypeId = 1
        };

        ClientEmailAddress email = new ClientEmailAddress {
            Client = client,
            EmailAddress = "test@test.com"
        };

       client.FkClientEmailAddresses.Add(email);
```

This will allow EF to track reference between the assigned client and email address and once real id is returned from the database EF should correctly set FK in your email address entity.

Comment: In your example, is 'Client' a navigational property?

Comment: Yes it is navigation property.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this to be the answer I was looking for; whilst this doesn't work for me - I believe it's to do with the MySQL/Connector not supporting unsigned foreign key columns.